# Django ModelForm save() overloading

Tags: python, django, polymorphism, django-forms

I am trying to define two different versions of the save() method for a ModelForm, but the only one being executed is the second one. When i try to save() i get error: save() takes at least 3 arguments, 1 given.

```
[...]
def save(self,commit=True):
    return super(NewProgramForm,self).save(commit=True)

def save(self, NameFile, SizeFile , commit=True):
    inst = super(NewProgramForm, self).save(commit=False)
    inst.size = SizeFile
    inst.sketches_file = NameFile
    inst.lines_of_code = 0

    if commit: inst.save()

    return inst
```

I'm quite sure the error is trivial, but i can't figure out what's wrong... 
Thank you in advance for any useful tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining multiple methods with the same name, but different attributes is called *method overloading* and is popular in languages such as Java. This is not permitted in Python - plain and simple.

You need to change the name of the second `save` method, or merge the methods into one method with `NameFile` and `SizeFile` having a default value (making them optional).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I admit I am a python newbie, and I had this doubt… I'll implement this another way, thanks again for the clarification.

Comment: Sure. One additional tip: There is a strong convention suggesting that pretty much everything that is **not** a class name (like method attributes) should start with a lowercase letter ([more about naming conventions in Python](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#prescriptive-naming-conventions))

Comment: Also, thanks for completing the answer with a suggestion for the implementation. Answer accepted, you're very kind!